# Using mongodb for querying substring

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, nosql

So, I'm using mongodb and trying to do a search for a substring in a key, if any document contains the substring it should return the document withing the query.

This is what im using:

```
db.events.find({name: '\.*substring\.'})
```

But it only matches some names, not every name that contains the substring...

I've tried using the $text and $search operator, but it seems that it only queries if I input the whole name, not the substring.

Comment: use regex for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
db.events.find({"name": {"$regex": ".*substring*.", "$options": "i"}}))
```

Use `$option` `i` if you wanted case insensitive.  You have all the options available as per mongo `$regex`, [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/). Or just remove altogether.

Comment: thanks, yours actually worked but different, cause yours is supposed to begin with the string, i used .*substring*. to match any that contains the substring... thanks!!

Comment: @MatheusRezende I’ve updated my answer